# code igniter 4 php form insert for database

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, frameworks, codeigniter-4

Im having troubles on how to push trough or save the data in the forms for the user to put in. Im kinda new to this framework and the tutorials or documentations from the framework itself is not that useful. Can anyone find a solution for this?
Here is the Routes of it.

```
<?php

namespace Config;

// Create a new instance of our RouteCollection class.
$routes = Services::routes();

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Router Setup
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Pages');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('view');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
// The Auto Routing (Legacy) is very dangerous. It is easy to create vulnerable apps
// where controller filters or CSRF protection are bypassed.
// If you don't want to define all routes, please use the Auto Routing (Improved).
// Set `$autoRoutesImproved` to true in `app/Config/Feature.php` and set the following to true.
// $routes->setAutoRoute(false);

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Route Definitions
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

// We get a performance increase by specifying the default
// route since we don't have to scan directories.
use App\Controllers\News;
use App\Controllers\Pages;
use App\Controllers\Form;
$routes->get('/', [Pages::class, 'view'], ['as' => 'pages.view']);
// $routes->match(['get', 'post'], 'create', [News::class, 'create']);
// $routes->get('news/(:segment)', [News::class, 'view']);
// $routes->get('news', [News::class, 'index']);
// $routes->get('pages', [Pages::class, 'index']);
// $routes->get('(:segment)', [Pages::class, 'view']);
$routes->get('form', [Form::class, 'index'], ['as' => 'form.index']);
$routes->post('form-add', [Form::class, 'add'], ['as' => 'form.add']);

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Additional Routing
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * There will often be times that you need additional routing and you
 * need it to be able to override any defaults in this file. Environment
 * based routes is one such time. require() additional route files here
 * to make that happen.
 *
 * You will have access to the $routes object within that file without
 * needing to reload it.
 */
if (is_file(APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php')) {
    require APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php';
}
```

Here is the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest;
use CodeIgniter\Files\File;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\News as News;

class Form extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        helper(['form', 'url']);

        return view('templates/header', [
                'title' => ucfirst("Upload")
            ])
            . view('pages/form')
            . view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function add()
    {
        helper(['form', 'url']);

        $request = service('request');
        $title = $request->getPost('title');
        $name = $request->getPost('name');
        $img = $request->getPost('image');

        $response = [
            'title' => $title,
            'name' => $name,
            'image' => $img
        ];
        return view('templates/header')
            . view('pages/load')
            . view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

and here is the form itself

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
      <form action="<?= route_to('form.add') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
       
      <?= csrf_field() ?>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="name" name="name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="title" name="title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="image-link">Image Link:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="image" name="image">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="mt-25 btn action-1 w-full" value ="Submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried following the create news thing on the documentation it doesn't work It doesnt save to the database itself. And when I looked at the server side it returned the page I was trying to redirect to after submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Named routes with dots in them aren't a good idea. Use hyphens or a different name instead.

In your controller method you don't write anything to the database, you just assign values to an array, but never do anything with it.

Saving to database:

```
$model = new NewsModel();
$news = [
            'title' => $title,
            'name' => $name,
            'image' => $img
        ];    
$result = $model->save($news);
```

Return data to the view:

```
return view('templates/header')
    . view('pages/load', ['news' => $news, 'result' => $result]) // or pass an array
    . view('templates/footer');
```

If you follow the 'Build your first application' section on the documentation completely it should definitely work (I personally did it a few times successfully).